# Is there a public statistics on duplicates?

Tags: feature-request, support, duplicate-questions, statistics

Was wondering if there is a way to see the **specific** subjects that "star" in SO.
I believe number of duplicates of a specific question can give good insight.
Is there such a statistic and if there is is, is it public?

Comment: Related: [Data and statistics regarding the subject of duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359641)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know about the [SE data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)? If you know SQL, perhaps you can compose a query for this. If not, you can always search for an existing one.

[I've found a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/91387/find-popular-originals-questions-referenced-in-duplicate-notices) that is probably closely related to what you want. It gives the number of duplicates per question.

A more simple way to do your research is to use the search bar and giving in some advanced parameters like `views:100000 score:100` (at least 100k views with a score of 100 or more).

Comment: did not know about the SE data explorer. This would be enough for me - thanks.