# Data and statistics regarding the subject of duplicate questions?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, data-explorer, statistics, duplicate-answers

Browsing the WordPress community, there seems to be many questions on the same exact problem, such as: *using `.htaccess` to redirect to HTTPS*... Obviously, we are not searching (enough) prior to asking.

Is there data available on the most commonly asked duplicate questions, including the site and the subject and date?

Also, would there be data to show if there has been an increase/decrease in questions for certain subjects overtime, for example - as new scripting languages become popular, so we might expect to see an increase in duplicate questions, and just as WordPress becomes more accessible and understandable to new users (developers), so we would see a decrease in duplicate questions.

In fact, I've just noticed the Query Stack Overflow service. Can it be used for this, i.e. is there a query repository available to run such queries?

Comment: There is the theory that if a subject matures, more and more potential questions would be duplicates and the emphasis should move from asking questions to searching for existing answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at the PostLinks table. It holds links to duplicate questions (LinkType = 3).

From [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)

> - `LinkTypeId` type of link
>   <sup>1 = Linked (PostId contains a link to RelatedPostId)</sup>
>   <sup>3 = Duplicate (PostId is a duplicate of RelatedPostId)</sup>

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/1358676) shows the top duplicate targets on Wordpress.se.

```
select relatedpostid as [Post Link]
     , count(*) [Number of duplicates]
from postlinks 
where linktypeid = 3
group by relatedpostid
order by count(*) desc
```

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: I see. So SEDE would allow for viewing active current (week) questions - and I've just found the search option for all duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes+htaccess+https